# .fadeOut not working with very simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, fadeout

I am trying to make a navigation menu for a blog I am working on, currently I am trying to make it where when the 'Home' tab is clicked on the other two fade out. I do not know why this code is not working as it is a pretty simple few lines of code. I am not going to add in the CSS as I do not believe it will have anything to do with this problem. Thank you!

---

```
<div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var main = function(){
  $('#hme').click(function(){
    $('#abt, #prt').fadeOut();
  });
}

document.ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the main function at all.

```
document.ready(main)
```

Should be the JQuery format:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wrap `document` in the JQuery object:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Wow rookie mistake haha. Thank you!

Comment: @Joshua haha, no worries

Answer (score 1):

Change like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='prt'>Portfolio</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var main = function(){
  $('#hme').click(function(){
    $('#abt, #prt').fadeOut();
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change document.ready function.
Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hme').click(function(){
$('#abt, #prt').fadeOut();
});
});
```